# How to retroactively add _id to subdocuments in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, backend, objectid

I have a collection with 100k documents, each containing a field which is an array of subdocuments.

These subdocuments do not have a unique `_id`.

How do I write a migration script to generate an ObjectId for each of those subdocuments?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following JS code, on mongo shell:

```
const docs = db.collection.find({}).toArray();
for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) 
{ 
   if (docs[i].array) {
      docs[i].array = docs[i].array.map(item => ({...item, _id: ObjectId()}))
   } 
   db.collection.replaceOne({_id: docs[i]._id}, docs[i])
}
```

In this snippet, we first fetch all the docs in a collection, loop over them and add `_id` in the array elements, then we replace the old doc with the new one.